# Html/Css font-family does not show the font for some element

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm writing a very basic site with only html/css. I downloaded some fonts (each font have only 1 file ttf/otf).
In localhost, (with Chrome) i wrote all, and all works perfectly.
When i put it on a server (in my case altervista) it does not work for altervista. Works only 1 font of 2 that i used.
For css file i have:

```
    @font-face 
    { 
        font-family: PirateOne; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        src: url('fonts/PirataOne-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face 
    { 
        font-family: SoTFont; 
        src: url('fonts/Windlass.ttf');
    }
```

for the 2 fonts.
So the first works good for all where i allocated it, the second one not. SO i tried to associate at the element with the second one, the first, but they continue to not work. I tried with 3others font (that in locally work).

In the index.html i have:

```
    <BODY id="bodyindex">

    <p class="title"> My Site </p>

     .........
    </body>
```

and in css file:

```
    p.title
    {
        font-size: 275%;
        font-family: SotFont;
        text-align: center;
        color: lightblue;
        margin: 20 0 0 0;
    }
```

and the same for other 2 p.
i tied with `font-family: "SotFont";`, with `font-family: PirateOne;`
or `font-family: "PirateOne";`

but nothing...in local all this test works perfectly and the font loads, but in altervista..nothing..it not load. How can i solve? Thank you

ps. i read some discussion on google, and in particular here, but nothing solved my problem also adding `format('truetype') or opentypè` haven't solved.

thank you

EDIT:
Chrome saved cache with err name of font usage. WIth Hidden Navigation i see that all fonts work correctly

Comment: Have you made sure you've actually uploaded both the fonts and the index file to your server? Are the fonts uploaded in a way where the reference (`url()`) still maps out correctly? Have you confirmed there are no conflicting / overwriting fonts in the F12 developer tools?

Comment: Yes i uploaded all the files via FTP from my folder to the altervista folder, and the name, the folder, and the position are correctly (all fonts are in the fonts folder, 1 works the other not). Yes also the index file is in a correct place.
I don't know how to see conflicting fonts from F12 console. @Obsidian Age

Comment: Hi, you used wrong font name in CSS, you defined 'SoTFont' but you used 'SotFont'. you used small t instead of capital T. you should use same font name. try it.

Comment: @VvV  Hi! I tried, but nothing, it stay with the standard font. I Have 4 Paragraph with that Font, and no one of them works

Comment: Have you checked the  P tag using chrome inspector? can you see the font name on the P tag? or check if it is overwriting by another font on the server.

Comment: Ok Now it perfectly works, with inspector i saw that it stay with SotFont also after the change. I don't know why chrome saved the cache. so in hidden navigation works good, thanks for help to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font name declared and used are different. Try aligning them and clear the cache and reload the browser. It should work for you.

Comment: yeah I edit the post, there are the cache that saved the previous verison of the site